# How to build a bittorrent tracker?

Tags: ubuntu, bittorrent

I'm trying to build a bittorrent tracker server on my ubuntu server.
I have already installed bittorrent,and it is serving well on 8099 port.
Then i tryed make a torrent file on my local computer with Bittorrent client,and setted the tracker to my tracker i builded above.But it throw a exception:

```
Requested download is not authorized for use with this tracker.
```

How to build my own bittorrent tracker?

Comment: If you are trying to make a .torrent file for a private tracker it won't work like for a normal torrent file. You'll have to do some extra steps. The tracker staff should be able to help.

Answer (score 4):

There are many available
[BitTorrent trackers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_tracker),
as any simple Google search can show.

A Wikipedia comparison between trackers can be
[found here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_BitTorrent_tracker_software),
among which
[Opentracker](https://erdgeist.org/arts/software/opentracker/)
is particularly popular and is used by Pirate Bay.

Not on the list is also
[python-bittorrent](https://github.com/JosephSalisbury/python-bittorrent).

Comment: And then how to build make a torrent file with my own tracker?

Comment: You should find that by following the above links.